Не работает ограничение (BasePermission has_object_permission)
Из-за чего не работает ограничение (BasePermission has_object_permission) запросов на PUT и DELETE запросы во ViewSet?
Это permision:
class AuthorOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.author == request.user

тут ViewSet:
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AuthorOrReadOnly, )
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    def list(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.validated_data['author'] = request.user
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        post = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(post)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        post = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(post, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        post = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(post, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        post = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        post.delete()
        return Response(status=204)

Когда я открываю свой URL-адрес для просмотра, он скрывает поля ввода для запросов исправления, удаления. Но, когда я отправляю запрос из shell, он просто редактирует любые объекты, не проверяя права. Поэтому, я думаю, что мое разрешение не работает.
Я попробовал заменить viewset на modelviewset, и всё заработало.
Так почему же ничего не работает и как исправить ViewSet?
